# for command for a copy process not working

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to use this command to copy one file into multiple sub-directories of folder.  It works fine until I change the target to something in the program files directory.  I can't seem to get it past the space between program and files.  I've tried to use a couple different variations of quotes and semi-colons but nothing seems to work.

```
for /F %f in ('dir c:\program files\target_folder /b/s/ad') do copy c:\send\text.txt %f
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put quotations around the whole location of where you are trying to put it, now I've never attempted this before so I don't know if you have tried it, but I would put the quotes around like this.

```
for /F %f in ('dir "c:\program files\target_folder" /b/s/ad') do copy c:\send\text.txt %f
```

Answer (score 1):

The space between "program" and "files" makes `dir` see two arguments,`c:\program` and `files\target_folder`. Make it parse the folder name as a single argument by surrounding the whole argument with double quotes: `"c:\program files\target_folder"`